# How to clear all input fields in p:dataTable?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0 with PrimeFaces. I have a `<p:dataTable>`. I have a `<p:inputText>` in a column. I can edit and save it. I have also a reset button, but it is not working.

```
<h:form id="f">
    <f:facet name="head">Enteri Karbon Hesaplaması</f:facet>
    <p:dataTable value="#{orderBean.orderList}" var="o" id="bir">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Hayvan Adi</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{o.hayvanadi}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Karbon Salinimi Değeri</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{o.karbonsalinimi}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Adet</f:facet>
            <p:inputText id="spinner"  maxlength="12" value="#{o.adet}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:commandButton value="Kaydet"  action="#{orderBean.saveAction()}" update="bir"/>
    <p:commandButton value="Temizle"  update="bir" process="@this" actionListener="#{orderBean.reset}"/>
</h:form>
```

Here is the relevant part of my backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class OrderBean {
    private static final ArrayList<Order> orderList = 
        new ArrayList<Order>(Arrays.asList(
            new Order("Süt İneği", 99 , 0),             
            new Order("Diğer İnekler", 58, 0),      
            new Order("Koyun",5, 0),
            new Order("Keçi",5, 0),     
            new Order("At ",18, 0),     
            new Order("Eşek ",10, 0)                
        )
    );

    public String saveAction() {
        for (Order order : orderList){
            order.setEditable(false);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String editAction(Order order) {
        order.setEditable(true);
        return null;
    }

    public void reset() {  
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("form:f");  
    }  

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the type of your command button to reset ie:

```
<p:commandButton type="reset" value="Temizle"  update="bir" process="@this" actionListener="#{orderBean.reset}"/>
```

Also, since you are basically trying to make the datatable empty again you can just set orderList to an empty list in the reset function.

Comment: If you only put ''Type="reset"'' all the input restart but doesnt go to other page... how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can reset a form using `<p:commandButton type="reset"` or `<p:commandButton update="@form"`. The latter is also used in `p:inplace`.

Edit: The reason your button isn't working is because the id referred in its update attribute isn't correct. It should be `:formId:dataTableId`. The `@form` is easier though.