# <p:resetInput> not working

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a piece of code:

```
<p:dialog dynamic="true" widgetVar="details" id="detailsDialog" position="center" closeOnEscape="true" resizable="false"
        header="#{prop['tum.editteam.detailsfor']} #{teamListController.selectedProjectsDTO.groupname}" modal="true" draggable="false"
        showEffect="fade" hideEffect="slide" height="500" width="1280" rendered="#{authenticationController.sessionUser.admin}" styleClass="teamEditStyle">
        <p:panel id="teamEditPanel">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/includes/editteamlist.xhtml"/>
        </p:panel>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="2">
                    <p:outputPanel layout="block" style="float:right;">
                        <p:commandButton value="#{prop['tum.addteam.resetbutton']}"
                            styleClass="buttonStyle" process="@this" update="teamEditPanel">
                            <p:resetInput target="teamEditPanel"/>
                        </p:commandButton>
                        <p:spacer width="10"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="#{prop['tum.editteam.updatebutton']}" 
                            onclick="confirmUpdateTeamEdit.show();" styleClass="buttonStyle"/>
                    </p:outputPanel>
                </p:column>
            </p:row>
        </f:facet>
    </p:dialog>
```

here,
the `<p:resetInput>` is not working.
Please Help, I dont understand why this is not working.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you already checked out this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20469082/1269441 Also, sending parts of your managedBean might be helpful...

Comment: @L-Ray: It works absolute fine!Thanks Bud!

Comment: awesome, consider upvoting the answer of the guy who wrote it there then... ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reset all fields in form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440079/reset-all-fields-in-form)